# Can winginx be trusted?

Tags: nginx, winginx

I recently installed winginx, because I wanted to try it out as an alternative to XAMPP.

I pressed yes on every confirmation for the software to "make chances to my computer", so that it could change the host files for me, even tho I could do it myself manually.

Wel long story short, now I'm scared and contemplating a reinstall of my OS. Paranoid or not?

Best regards

Comment: What is the justification for your paranoia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are scared or have fears about what the software does or does not, 
then it might be a better choice, to use a server stack for windows, which is open-source.

You would have the chance to inspect the source-code of the installation wizard(s), the build-toolchain, the inner workings of the control panel and the hosts editor. It depends on opinion, but given your fears and contemplation, then maybe https://github.com/WPN-XM would be a better choice (shameless plug).

Comment: I don't mind if you advertise for your project because it looks promising. I will check it out for sure. Thanks